# iOS, which database to choose?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, xcode, database-design

i need some advice.

I am developing an iPhone application (later for Android also) using some social network users. I need to store some data in a database online.

Better to use MySQL with XML or directly use SQLite?
I want performance and stability, and if all goes as I think I might have to handle 500,000 users or more.

I studied a lot about databases, but I would not even take care of his administration, because I'm alone.
Most web services do not support SQLite, but MySQL only.

Can anyone give me some advice with justified?

Thank you to entire community.
Bye, Eros.

Comment: If You use this database in android also then not use SQLite I think that is not supported in android.SO use MYSQL with xml or json that will be good.

Comment: @vishiphone SQLite is the only supported Database on both Android and iOS. But you should never ever allow direct acces to the Database form the internet. Just use a JSON based webservice to comunicate to the server.

Comment: Sorry buddy I am Not confident on that(sqlite in android) but Yes your that point is correct json based web services is good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the database going to run on the device (iPhone/Android) or in the server? In the device both iPhone and Android have good support for running SQLite as an embedded database. If you are thinking server side it doesn't really matter in terms of compatibility since most likely you will add a application layer that is easy to make compatible.

Comment: In a server. So, i need of a software server-side?

Comment: In the server you would use a combination of server-side program and an sql database. Common combinations are php/mysql and asp/sqlserver. You would communicate with the app using some http-based protocol. The iphone sends HTTP requests and the server responds un XML or JSon (for most cases I like json better. XML is an overkill). Both the iPhone and Android can perform these tasks comfortably. I would recommend getting confortable in something like php-mysql and move from there. Hope this helps!